# knockout mapping example not working on IE9

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-9, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is a fairly basic knockout mapping example on jsfiddle. Works on pretty much every browser other than IE9. Does anybody know why? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/KXhem/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the script is not loading on IE9:

Script from https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch

Can you link the file in another server different than github specifying "text/javascript" as mime-type. Or try linking not a debug version: see this dicusion: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/585

The raw files are not served with the correct mime type from Github, as they likely don't intend to be a server for the content.